# Avoid line break in a table header at the ipython notebook markdown cell.

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to create a table in a markdown cell in an ipython notebook:

```
| $X_{t-1}$         | $X_{t}$           | $\textbf{P} (X_{t}| X_{t-1}) $|  
| -------------     |-------------| ----------------------------------|
| $\textit{False}$  | $\textit{False}$  | 0.7                         |
| $\textit{False}$  | $\textit{True}$   | 0.3                         |
| $\textit{True}$   | $\textit{False}$  | 0.3                         |
| $\textit{True}$   | $\textit{True}$   | 0.7                         |
```

However, a title of the table is breaking in two lines. The result is like this.

[image]

I tried to change the alignment using the following commands without any result:

```
 :--- or --- = left align
 ---: = right align
 :---: = centered
```

How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the correct method but here is a quick fix. Add a tab at the beginning of your header

```
| $X_{t-1}$         | $X_{t}$           | &nbsp; $\textbf{P} (X_{t}| X_{t-1}) $       |  
| -------------     |-------------------| --------------------------------------------|
| $\textit{False}$  | $\textit{False}$  | 0.7                                         |
| $\textit{False}$  | $\textit{True}$   | 0.3                                         |
| $\textit{True}$   | $\textit{False}$  | 0.3                                         |
| $\textit{True}$   | $\textit{True}$   | 0.7                                         |
```

Comment: Quick and dirty. I like it.  Thanks!