# jupyter notebook html table cannot display

Tags: html, jupyter

why jupyter notebook cannot display html 'table', but other html elements are okay, and how can I solve this problem?

below is my source code and my result

source code

```
<table style="width:20%">
     <tr> 
       <td> **L1** </td> 
       <td> 1.1 </td> 
     </tr>
</table>
```

result

```
 <tr> 
   <td> **L1** </td> 
   <td> 1.1 </td> 
 </tr>
```

it only removes tag `<table>` and does nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting, because the table (created by pasting your code) comes out just fine for me:[image: output]

From my personal experience, I can definitely say that Markdown in jupyter notebooks is somehow volatile/unpredictable when it comes to HTML. For example, I myself have been looking for a fix for Jupyter just arbitrarily doing line breaks in the table header (esp. in formulas) and I have found [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135551/avoid-line-break-in-a-table-header-at-the-ipython-notebook-markdown-cell), but it doesn't work for me at all.

I know this is not particularly helpful, but at least it demonstrates that the table not being rendered correctly in your case was either some unexpected behaviour or some bug which maybe, or maybe not, has been fixed in the course of the last year.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the magic command before the table tag, which worked for me.

[image]